# Vue3 access component data attribute from console

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, laravel-mix-vue3

How do I access a component data attribute value from the console in Vue 3?

When I was working in vue2 I was accessing this using `$vm0` and setting and getting any component attribute value but this does not work in Vue 3.

Vue.js devtools screenshot with data:

[image]

Here I want to access `isCalendarAttached` from Chrome console but I am not able to:

[image]

Here is my app object which is the root component:

[image]

Is there any way I can access that variable from console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Vue.js devtools [v6.0.0+](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd):

```js
$vm0.ctx.isCalendarAttached // Read-only
$vm0.ctx.$data.isCalendarAttached // Read/Write
```

Or if your state is moved into `setup` per [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#setup-component-option):

```js
$vm0.setupState.isCalendarAttached
```

Note:

1. Vue.js devtools v5 does not support Vue 3 so v6 is required.
2. You'll still need to ensure you've first selected your Vue component in the devtools.